# How to paste in an email a table with google script/google sheets Macros?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this Macro to send emails to some people. The problem is that it pastes the table in values, not in table format. I need to paste the table as a table.

```
    function Mails() {
 var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
 var filas= values[0][1];
 var columnas= values[1][0];

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Enviar"));
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,4,filas,columnas);
 var data = dataRange.getValues();

 for (i in data) {
 var rowData = data[i];
 var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue();
 var destinatario = rowData[0];
 var sigla1 = sheet.getRange(2,4,filas,columnas).getValues();
 var mensaje = 'Estimado ' + destinatario + ',\n\n' + sigla1 ;
 var asunto = 'Mensajes Pendientes';
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, asunto, mensaje);
 }
}

function onOpen () {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var menuItems = [
{name: 'Send Emails', functionName: 'Mails'}
];
spreadsheet.addMenu('Enviar Emails', menuItems);

}
```

The problem is this line  var sigla1 = `sheet.getRange(2,4,filas,columnas).getValues();`
I have to paste it as a table, not in values. How can i do that?

Thanks

I'am trying with this code now.. but it doesn't function..

```
function Mails() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Enviar"));
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
 var filas= values[0][1];
 var columnas= values[1][0];

 var recipient = sheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue();
 var subject = 'Estimado';

 var vA=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Enviar').getDataRange().getValues();
 var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}<table>";
 for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    html+="<tr>";
    for(var j=0;i<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(i==0) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>', vA[i][j]);
      }else{
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', vA[i][j]);
      }
    }
    html+="</tr>";
  }

  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, null, {htmlBody:html})

}

function onOpen () {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var menuItems = [
{name: 'Send Emails', functionName: 'Mails'}
];
spreadsheet.addMenu('Enviar Emails', menuItems);

}
```

[Here you have an image of what i need to send via email.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36mkf.png)

The rows change with the data, so the table depend of how many operations are in the day..

Comment: Saying that something doesn't work doesn't help.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I wrote that i think this part is not working "The problem is this line var sigla1 = sheet.getRange(2,4,filas,columnas).getValues(); I have to paste it as a table, not in values. How can i do that?"...

Answer (score 0):

## Html Table into Email

```
function sendHtmlTableViaEmail() {
  var vA=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('name').getDataRange().getValues();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}<table>";
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    html+="<tr>";
    for(var j=0;i<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(i==0) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>', vA[i][j]);
      }else{
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', vA[i][j]);
      }
    }
    html+="</tr>";
  }
 //You have to add the code for recipient and subject
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, null, {htmlBody:html})

}
```

Comment: But with that code, how I select the range of the google sheet (calc sheet) i wanted to send?

Comment: It's not clear to me what data you wish to tabularize and what data you wish to use to send emails.  And since your tables are mostly in Spanish looking at images of them doesn't help me because I don't speak Spanish.

Comment: I'am sorry for my english, I'am from Argentina. I have that table that get information from other sheets, so the number of rows are changing all days. I need to send that table getting all rows. For that purpose i used a formula that count the number of rows "var sigla1 = sheet.getRange(2,4,filas,columnas).getValues();". But the problem is that it paste the table as text. I need to paste it in a table format..

Comment: If I could take a look at your spreadsheet perhaps I could figure out what you are trying to accomplish.